# I have a JSON object, it contains an array of array elements, how do I get those elements into my HTML page using ionic 2 framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

JSON object contains `array` of arrays, I want the second array of arrays into my HTML page using Ionic 2 framework... Please help... I tried all my possibilities and I am using `*ngFor` in HTML page....

Comment: Can you please add the structure of the JSON-object and the code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping stackoverflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.